# SunLDAP Schema Extensions to support Linux/Unix Authentication + Sudo

Tags: linux, ldap, solaris, pam, pam-ldap

We are running SunLDAP (Sun/Oracle Directory server 11), and would like our Linux/Unix machines to authenticate against LDAP and also use LDAP for storing SUDO policies. What Schema Extensions are required for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No schema change is required for Authentication - posixAccount, posixGroup etc work fine for me.

I haven't implemented sudo in ODSEE, but did research the topic a while ago. There's loads of documentation online - see the sudo LDAP [documentation](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.16/sudoers.ldap.man.html)  or Solaris community forums for the current schema extensions.